# React Native app won't work after splashScreen because of expo-updates

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

My react-native app is working correctly in Debug build but not in Release

Error :

**The embedded manifest is invalid or could not be read. Make sure you have configured expo-updates correctly in your Xcode Build Phases**

I've tried to rebuild, install expo-updates again, pod install, delete node modules... I want expo update to be working
[image]

Comment: What version of expo-updates are you using?

Comment: "expo-updates": "~0.10.15",